# I can no longer type backslash in Ubuntu on a Lenovo P50 with a UK keyboard after upgrading to 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, upgrade, keyboard, lenovo, keyboard-layout

After recent updates, I can no longer select a keyboard layout that works for my machine.

I have a Lenovo P50 laptop with a UK keyboard. The backslash key is on the bottom left, next to the "z"; It's currently typing "<" instead of backslash.

For whatever reason, there is no longer an option to select a keyboard layout compatable with the Lenovo P50 UK keyboard --- there are several Lenovo thinkpad options, but none of them match this machine. An appropriate option was available prior to the upgrade to 20.04.

What I can I do to get backslash back?

```
> cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS"
```

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you running? 

Comment: Ah very sorry! I've added that.

Comment: Lenovo AFAIK does not use any non-standard keyboard layouts.

Comment: Ok, well, I can't find any keyboard layout in the system that resembles the keyboard that's on my laptop. I don't imagine the keyboard is nonstandard, especially as it was working fine until the most recent distribution upgrade. But none of the new layouts seem to support the backslash key in the Lenovo UK keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like Ubuntu lost the UK language support during the upgrade, reverting instead to US English. This silently removed support for UK keyboard layouts. Here's what I did to fix things:

- Go to Control Center → Personal → Language Support
- Click "install/remove language" and add "UK English" as a language
- Drag "UK English" to the top of them menu
- Reboot
- Navigate to Control Center → Hardware → Keyboard
- Go to the "Layouts" tab
- Click "+ Add" and add UK English
- Remove US English
- Click "Reset to Defaults"